# Python Pandas dropping Non numerical rows from columns

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have a dataframe and want to drop the non numerical rows in the column `Score`

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({
'Score': [4.0,6,'3 1/3',7,'43a'],
'Foo': ['Nis','and stimpy','d','cab','abba'],
'Faggio':[0,1,0,1,0]
})
```

The result I want should look like:

```
   Faggio         Foo  Score
0       0         Nis      4
1       1  and stimpy      6
3       1         cab      7
```

I have tried:

```
ds=df[df['Score'].apply(lambda x: str(x).isnumeric())]

print(ds)

ds2=df[df['Score'].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit())]

print(ds2)
```

But both of them erased the column with the float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for checking `NaN` values, because your function return `NaN` if not number. Better and faster is use [text method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary) `str.isnumeric()` and `str.isdigit()` with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print df['Score'].str.isnumeric()
0      NaN
1      NaN
2    False
3      NaN
4    False
Name: Score, dtype: object

print df['Score'].str.isnumeric().isnull()
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Score, dtype: bool

print df[df['Score'].str.isnumeric().isnull()]
   Faggio         Foo Score
0       0         Nis     4
1       1  and stimpy     6
3       1         cab     7

print df[df['Score'].str.isdigit().isnull()]
   Faggio         Foo Score
0       0         Nis     4
1       1  and stimpy     6
3       1         cab     7
```

Similar solution with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
print df[pd.to_numeric(df['Score'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
   Faggio         Foo Score
0       0         Nis     4
1       1  and stimpy     6
3       1         cab     7
```

Comment: Not on the example but on my real data I would get this error "Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"

Comment: No problem, you can add casting to string - `df['Score'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()`

Comment: Thanks I did not remember you can coerce the data type

Comment: Ok, I try add similar solution. Thank you for accepting. If you want, you can upvote too. Thanks.

Comment: funny thing when errors are not coerced some csv sheets are all blank. So I think `df[pd.to_numeric(df['Score'], errors='coerce').notnull()]` is the best solution